# em_postgresql On Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, eventmachine

I'm running a rails app on a thin server. I'm using an eventmachine [based postgres driver](https://github.com/leftbee/em-postgresql-adapter)  which runs perfectly on my local machine.

When I try and deploy on heroku, the `em_postgres` driver doesn't work and the app can't connect to the database. Locally, I set the adapter in my `config/database.yml` file to be `em_postgresql` instead of postgres. Since Heroku overwrites your `database.yml` file, I tried changing the adapter in the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable but that has not worked and it still seems to be trying to use the standard postgres driver.

Does anyone know how to properly configure the database adapter in Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku generates the database.yml file and always puts the adapter to "postgresql"

To override this you can override the database_configuration method

in your config/application.rb file you can add the following to update the config before activerecord loads it

```
def config.database_configuration
  parsed = super
  parsed[Rails.env]['adapter'] = "em_postgresql"
  parsed[Rails.env]['pool'] = 20
  parsed
end
```